# Cannot borrow `**...` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference

Tags: vector, rust, lifetime

I want to iterate through a vector of pointers. The vector is contained inside a struct, and the pointer points to the same struct, like a tree.

The vector is `self.groups`. I tried to loop over it, and call a (mutable) method, `push_group()`, but I got the error `error[E0596]: cannot borrow **g as mutable, as it is behind a & reference`.

I tried adding `iter_mut()`, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Playground : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=14d911a460079a4eb747d6b10361fa60

The code for reference :

```rust
pub struct Group<'a> {
    pub name: String,
    pub groups: Vec<&'a Group<'a>>
}

impl<'a> Group<'a> {
    // Append a node under a node named "parent_name"
    pub fn push_group(&mut self, group: &'a Group<'a>, parent_name: &str) -> bool {
        if self.name == parent_name {
            self.groups.push(group);
            return true;
        }

        for g in self.groups.iter_mut() {
            let found = g.push_group(group, parent_name); // Error: cannot borrow as mutable
            if found {
                return found;
            }
        }

        false
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut group = Group { name: "PATIENT_RESULT".to_string(), groups: vec![] };
    let other_group = Group { name: "OBSERVATION".to_string(), groups: vec![] };
    let _ = group.push_group(&other_group, "PATIENT_RESULT");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need `Group` to own its children groups, not just have a reference to them (this is not strictly necessary, you can go with mutable references, but this is likely what you want):

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Group {
    pub name: String,
    pub groups: Vec<Group>,
}

impl Group {
    // Append a node under a node named "parent_name"
    pub fn push_group(&mut self, group: Group, parent_name: &str) -> bool {
        if self.name == parent_name {
            self.groups.push(group);
            return true;
        }

        for g in self.groups.iter_mut() {
            let found = g.push_group(group, parent_name);
            if found {
                return found;
            }
        }

        false
    }
}
```

But this will still error with:

```rust
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `group`
  --> src/main.rs:15:38
   |
8  |     pub fn push_group(&mut self, group: Group, parent_name: &str) -> bool {
   |                                  ----- move occurs because `group` has type `Group`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
15 |             let found = g.push_group(group, parent_name);
   |                                      ^^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

The problem is that Rust thinks that you may push the same group twice, but a group needs to have only one owner. This cannot happen because as soon as we push the group we return `true` and exit, but Rust doesn't know that. To make Rust happy, a common workaround is to use `Option` with [`.take().unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take):

```rust
pub fn push_group(&mut self, group: Group, parent_name: &str) -> bool {
    fn push_impl(this: &mut Group, group: &mut Option<Group>, parent_name: &str) -> bool {
        if this.name == parent_name {
            this.groups.push(group.take().unwrap());
            return true;
        }

        for g in this.groups.iter_mut() {
            let found = push_impl(g, group, parent_name);
            if found {
                return found;
            }
        }
        
        false
    }
    push_impl(self, &mut Some(group), parent_name)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It solved my problem + it simplifies my code a lot ! I've got a long way to master rust ^^' I didn't know you could declare a function inside a method like that, pretty neat ! Thanks again :D